# How can I use a variable from all similar objects in an if statement (Java)?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and I hit a small snag.

I'm writing some code for an imaginary bank, and I want to include all the accounts' balance into one if statement. I made a double called `accountBalance` that I use for each account.
For example, `Josie.accountBalance = 1200`. `Josie` is an object for the `BankAccounts` type I created.

I want to make an if statement, so that if the account balance is above 1000, the bank sends a message warning the account about this issue, and it refunds everything above 1000$.

I could just do an if statement for every account I create, and write my code there, but I was wondering if there was a way to write an if statement that applied to all the `BankAccounts` type, without having to specify the names.

Thanks.

Here's the code that I wrote.

```
package learnJavaNew;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BankAccounts {

    final static double defaultBalance = 50;
    final static double maxBalance = 1000;
    static double oldBalance;
            
    static int employees;
    
    static double bankMoney;
    static double accountBalance;
    static double newBalance;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Josie's Bank Account
        BankAccounts Josie = new BankAccounts();
        Josie.depositMoney(0);
        Josie.accountBalance = defaultBalance + newBalance;
        System.out.println(Josie.accountBalance);
        
        Josie.withdrawMoney(25.64);
        Josie.accountBalance = defaultBalance + newBalance;
        System.out.println(Josie.accountBalance);
        
        // Dan's Bank Account
        BankAccounts Dan = new BankAccounts();
        Dan.depositMoney(1000);
        Dan.accountBalance = defaultBalance + newBalance;
        System.out.println(Dan.accountBalance);
        
        Dan.withdrawMoney(5);
        Dan.accountBalance = defaultBalance + newBalance;
        System.out.println(Dan.accountBalance);
        
        // Accounts List
        ArrayList<BankAccounts> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccounts>();
        accounts.add(Josie);
        accounts.add(Dan);
        System.out.println(accounts);
        
        // Max Balance
        if(accountBalance >= maxBalance) {
            
            System.out.println("You have reached the maximum balance for your bank account, which is " + maxBalance + "$.");
            System.out.println("You cannot deposit more money into this account.");
            oldBalance = accountBalance;
            accountBalance = 1000;
            System.out.println("You have been refunded " + (oldBalance - accountBalance));
            
        }
        
        // New Balance
        System.out.println(Dan.accountBalance);
        System.out.println(Josie.accountBalance);
    }
    
    public void depositMoney(double depositedMoney) {
        
        newBalance = depositedMoney;

    }
    
    public void withdrawMoney(double withdrawnMoney) {
        
        newBalance = newBalance - withdrawnMoney;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you create each object separately? It sounds like they should be in a container of some kind, e.g.: an `ArrayList`

Comment: I created an arraylist with the names of each account, but how do I apply that to an if statement?

Comment: You want an arraylist of the objects, not of some names. And then you just iterate through the list

Comment: I think you should show your code.  This discussion is far too hypothetical for any real answers.

Comment: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added my code into the post.

Comment: Your static fields to do with an individual account should not be static. If the `BankAccounts` class is supposed to represent a bank account (as you are trying to use it), then each account needs its own balance.

Comment: @khelwood Ok... Well is there another, more efficient, way to make bank accounts? You are saying that I need to make a variable for each account if I use the class as an account. Is there another way?

Comment: Never use `static` (except for `static void main`) until you can specifically explain why its use is appropriate in a given case. This rule will save you many headaches as you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of depends on the result you want.  If the above code gives you the right result, then it's fine.  However I would probably do something like this, and omit the loop and the list entirely.

```
public void depositMoney(double depositedMoney) {
    if( depositedMoney + accountBalance > 1000 )
       System.out.println( "Maximum exceeded, not processed" );
    else
       accountBalance += depositedMoney;

}
```

Notice here that I've *changed* the previous operation of `depositedMoney`, including the fact that the method never updated `accountBalance`.

To refund money over an amount, you might return a value indicating the amount refunded.

```
public double depositMoney(double depositedMoney) {
    double refund = 0;
    if( depositedMoney + accountBalance > 1000 ) {
      refund = depositedMoney + accountBalance - 1000;
      accountBalance = 1000;
      System.out.println( "Maximum exceeded, refund " + refund );
    }  
       
    else
       accountBalance += depositedMoney;
    return refund;
}
```

Also, you really should be using instance variables.  Remove the static keyword.

```
double bankMoney;
double accountBalance;
double newBalance;
```

Comment: The account and new balance needs not to be static for this to work

Comment: Yup, noticed that after I answered.  Fixed now.

Comment: This code works, but I was wondering that instead of cancelling the deposit, we just add the money up to 1000. So, if I were to deposit 1200$, my balance would be 1000$ (assuming I had 0 at the start), and the additional 200$ would be refunded. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be made clearer by a different object model.

I would propose a BankAccount class (not "a BankAccounts class" -- that would mean that an object is "a BankAccounts", a jarring concept) and a Bank class.

```
  class BankAccount {
     private String owner;
     private double balance;

     BankAccount(String s, double b) { owner = s; balance = b; }

     String owner() { return owner; }
     double balance() { return balance; }

     void deposit(double amount) { … like before … }
     void withdraw(double amount) { … like before … }
  }
```

and

```
  class Bank {
     static List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         // set up some accounts
         BankAccount josie = new BankAccount("Josie", 0);
         accounts.add(josie);
         BankAccount dan = new BankAccount("Dan", 1000);
         accounts.add(dan);
          :
          etc
          :

         // print them all
         double total = 0;
         for (BankAccount acnt : accounts) {
             System.out.printf("Account %s : balance %s %n",
                               acnt.owner(), acnt.balance());
             total += acnt.balance();
         }
         System.out.printf("Total value of accounts: %s %n", total);
     }
  }
```

The benefit of this approach is that it makes it clearer what operations are for a single account and what operations are on "all accounts".